# Laravel 4 Custom Auth Provider - class not found error

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I am trying to implement a custom auth provider by following this guide: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/115/using-your-own-authentication-driver

In my project, I have created the following file:

**app/Latheesan/Extensions/DummyAuthProvider.php**

with the sample code from Step #1 and renamed "`MyApp`" to "`Latheesan`".

I then went to add the following line in my **app/start/global.php**

```
Auth::extend('dummy', function($app) {
    return new Latheesan\Extensions\DummyAuthProvider;
});
```

Then updated the **app/auth/config.php** and changed the driver like so:

```
'driver' => 'dummy',
```

Finally I amended my `routes.php` like this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function($route, $request) {
    if (Auth::guest())
        return Redirect::guest('login');
});

Route::get('login',  array('uses' => 'HomeController@showLogin'));
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogin'));
Route::get('logout', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogout'));

Route::get('/', function() {
    return View::make('hello');
})->before('auth');
```

Before I tested my code, I ran the **composer dump-auto** to generate autoload files.

When I visited my test site: http://laravel-test.local I am getting this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>   (E_ERROR)  Class 'Latheesan\Extensions\DummyAuthProvider' not found

Any idea why my custom auth provider class isn't loading?

Comment: Are you using PSR in composer.json so it knows how to autoload your classes? Something like this: `"autoload": { "classmap": (...), "psr-0": { "Latheesan": "app/" } },`

Comment: @milz Thanks for that, it worked. I am getting a different error, see my reply below for *Bogdan*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default composer doesn't know how to autoload your new class, so you would need to add an PSR rule in the `autoload` section of your `composer.json` file. This should do the trick:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Latheesan": "app/"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I am no longer getting that error about missing class. Now I have a different error: **Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script** http://i.imgur.com/0EOq9KL.png (p.s. I did `composer dump-auto` again after updating the `composer.json` file)

Comment: Never mind; I've fixed the error thanks to this post (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/issues/70). I had a white space at the beginning of my script.